# Achieve rendering of Semantic UI Icon within button_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, icons, semantic-ui

I am trying to achieve a button_to which looks like a link (class="btn btn-link") and which has as its text (input) value a semantic-ui icon. I need the button to display in-line as a link. I am using the semantic-ui-rails gem. My button-to is formatted as below:

```
<%= button_to semantic_icon('lightbulb outline'),
                  votes_path,
                  options: {
                      params: {
                          voter_id: current_user.id,
                          target_type: "Comment",
                          target_id: comment.id,
                          value: 1
                      }
                  },
                  class: "btn btn-link",
                  remote: true
    %>
```

However, the button displays on my screen as
    `<i class="lightbulb outline icon"></i>`
Instead of rendering the lightbulb-outline icon itself.

What must I change to get the value of the input tag of the button-to form to render properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
<%= button_to votes_path, class: "btn btn-link", remote: true, params: {
                                                                voter_id: current_user.id,
                                                                target_type: "Comment",
                                                                target_id: comment.id,
                                                                value: 1
                                                              } do %>
  <%= semantic_icon('lightbulb outline') %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That renders the icon as desired. Now the icon will not render inline though, instead it takes up its own line in my text. (I've updated the question to reflect this requirement).

Comment: For completeness: I added the following after "remote: true":
    form: {style: 'display:inline-block;'}
and got the form to render inline as I desired.